# How long after eating blue cheese would it take a dog show symptoms

Tags: dogs, diet

I read that it can be harmful for a dog to eat blue cheese, and that doing so can result in various symptoms if it affects the dog.

- vomiting
- diarrhoea
- convulsions
- fever

If a dog is going to experience these symptoms after eating blue cheese, how long would they take to appear?

Here are some examples of arcticles that say bluecheese is dangerous for dogs

- [Purina: Can Dogs Eat Cheese?](https://www.purina.co.uk/articles/dogs/feeding/what-dogs-eat/can-dogs-eat-cheese#:%7E:text=No,%20never%20give%20your%20dog,Vomiting)

Comment: If your dog ate that cheese, you should see a veterinarian as soon as possible, instead of just browsing the net hoping that some strangers will give you competent medical advice - especially after not being able to see the dog. Just saying.

Comment: https://www.purina.co.uk/articles/dogs/feeding/what-dogs-eat/can-dogs-eat-cheese#:~:text=No,%20never%20give%20your%20dog,Vomiting. seems to be a source

Comment: There are also pet poison hotlines you can call that you can get a consult from, in other words, they'll ask you questions about your pet and advise you what to do. Be warned that they aren't free and cost as much as a vet visit, but sometimes they may even know more about specific poisonous substances than your vet.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that is one of the articles I've come across. Should I be including sources here?

Comment: Context would be helpful here - "I read somewhere" can be 'important' or 'something someone made up' . That said, if your dog *actually* ate blue cheese, naturally, *please* contact a vet or poison control specialist